# Show a function is $K$-Lipschitz

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, lipschitz-functions

The following is the proof taken from [Lemma $13$](http://www.impan.pl/~pwojtas/Publikacje/freespaces.pdf).

[image]

Questions:

$(1)$: What is the Lipschitz-norm of $\phi_a$? The following is my attempt:

$\| \phi_a \|_{Lip} = \sup_{x \neq y}{\frac{|f(a) - \bar{g}(a)| |\tau(\| x - a \| - \tau(\| y - a \| |}{\| x - y \|}} = |f(a) - \bar{g}(a)| \sup_{x \neq y}{\frac{|\tau(\| x - a \| - \tau(\| y - a \| |}{\| x - y \|}}$.
My guess is $\| \phi_a \|_{Lip} = |f(a) - \bar{g}(a)| \| \phi_a \|_{Lip}$, but I couldn't show it.

$(2)$: How to show a function $f$ is $K$-Lipschitz? Is it enough to show that $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq K |x-y|$ for some constant $K$? Assume that $f$ is a real-valued function defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

$(3)$: Why can we assume that $K>1$?

Answer (score 1):

(1) See the Wikipedia entry on [Holder spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition#H.C3.B6lder_spaces). The Lipschitz norm is the special case $\alpha = 1$.

(2) Yes, this is what it means to prove that $f$ is $K$-Lipschitz.

(3) If $f$ is $M$-Lipschitz, then $f$ is also $K$-Lipschitz for any $K>M$. So if you know $f$ is Lipschitz, then you can assume it has a Lipschitz constant as large as you like; in particular, it is safe to assume $K>1$.

Comment: For first question, how does the Holder spaces wiki page helps in answering the question?

Comment: @Idontknow The Holder norms $\|\cdot\|_{C^{k,\alpha}}$ are defined in the subsection "Holder spaces." The Lipschitz norm is the special case $\alpha = 1$.